# Service worker cache breaks PDFs after the first load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, service-worker

I'm using [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox) to enable caching on one of my clients websites. It typically works well, except for some reason it's breaking PDFs after the first load. I suspect that when it saves the PDFs to the cache they're somehow getting corrupted, but I can still save the PDF locally from the broken page and it'll open just fine.

This is my service worker:

```
((global) => {
    // disable the service worker for post previews
    global.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
        if (event.request.url.match(/preview=true/)) {
            return;
        }
    });

    // ensure the service worker takes over as soon as possible
    global.addEventListener("install", event => event.waitUntil(global.skipWaiting()));
    global.addEventListener("activate", event => event.waitUntil(global.clients.claim()));

    // set up the cache
    global.toolbox.precache(["/", "/offline/"]);

    global.toolbox.router.get("/wp-content/uploads/(.*)", toolbox.cacheFirst);
    global.toolbox.router.get("/(.*)", toolbox.networkFirst, { NetworkTimeoutSeconds: 5 });

    // redirect offline queries to offline page
    self.toolbox.router.get("/(.*)", function (req, vals, opts) {
        return toolbox.networkFirst(req, vals, opts).catch((error) => {
            if (req.method === "GET" && req.headers.get("accept").includes("text/html")) {
                return toolbox.cacheOnly(new Request("/offline/"), vals, opts);
            }

            throw error;
        });
    });
})(self);
```

Some things I've tried:

- Add an additional route `global.toolbox.router.get("/wp-content/uploads/(.*).pdf", toolbox.networkOnly);`
- Change `/wp-content/uploads/(.*)` route to redirect to the PDF URL with the header "no-cache"

  ```
  global.toolbox.router.get("/wp-content/uploads/(.*)", function (req, vals, opts) {
      if (req.url.match(/\.pdf$/)) {
          const pdf_headers = new Headers();

          pdf_headers.append("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

          return toolbox.networkOnly(new Request(req.url, {
              method:  "GET",
              headers: pdf_headers,
              mode:    "same-origin",
              cache:   "no-cache",
          }), vals, opts);
      } else {
          return toolbox.cacheFirst;
      }
  });
  ```
- Excluding PDFs the same way that `preview=true` is exclude:

  ```
  global.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
      if (event.request.url.match(/preview=true/) || event.request.url.match(/\.pdf$/)) {
          return;
      }
  });
  ```

I'm out of ideas and would appreciate some guidance. Testing page is available here: https://www.westmontparks.org/about-us/board-minutesbid-docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is likely related to [this chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918944#c8) that is affecting Chrome version 71.

Comment: Aha! I thought it might be a browser bug, but couldn't turn anything up searching. Thanks much, will look in to it more on Monday

Comment: Actually, there was another ticket linked from the one above.

The ticket below is the more likely cause.  It is fixed in Chrome Canary, and should be merged into v72, per the comments on the ticket.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916514